# Using ant sshexec() in Grails forked JVM

Tags: grails

I'm running into an issue when using the forked JVM environment included with Grails (version 2.3 and above). Everything works just fine without the forked environment, I'm just trying to understand what's causing things to stop working correctly with it enabled. I'm trying to execute commands on a remote server via Groovy's `AntBuilder` helper class. The `sshexec()` method continues to throw an error—it can't find the jars needed for sshexec (which I have added a dependency for).

```
def ant = new AntBuilder()

try  {
    ant.sshexec(host: host, username: name, passphrase: pass, command: 'echo test', outputproperty: 'result')
}
catch(Exception e)  {
    throw new Exception("${ant.project.properties.'result'}")
}
```

I can run something like `ant.echo("hello")` ok, so it seems to be sshexec related. I'm using the default settings in `BuildConfig.groovy`:

```
grails.project.fork = [
    // configure settings for compilation JVM, note that if you alter the Groovy version forked compilation is required
    //  compile: [maxMemory: 256, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],

    // configure settings for the test-app JVM, uses the daemon by default
    test: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],
    // configure settings for the run-app JVM
    run: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
    // configure settings for the run-war JVM
    war: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
    // configure settings for the Console UI JVM
    console: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256]
]
```

If I comment out this whole section, eliminating the forked execution environment, everything works fine. I understand that the forked JVM isolates the build classpath from the runtime classpath. Does this stop Grails from pulling in the required dependencies? Not sure why just commenting out `grails.project.fork` fixes everything. Thanks!

**EDIT:**

Here's my dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes e.g.
    runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.24'

    runtime "com.jcraft:jsch:0.1.46"
    runtime "org.apache.ant:ant-jsch:1.8.2"
}
```

And the caught exception:

```
Problem: failed to create task or type sshexec
Cause: the class org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.ssh.SSHExec was not found.
        This looks like one of Ant's optional components.
Action: Check that the appropriate optional JAR exists in
        -ANT_HOME/lib
        -the IDE Ant configuration dialogs
Do not panic, this is a common problem.
The commonest cause is a missing JAR.
This is not a bug; it is a configuration problem
```

Comment: I suspect you have the jsch JAR (which is required for sshexec) on a parent classloader somewhere when running non-forked but not when running forked - try adding an explicit `compile` or `runtime` dependency on [jsch](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.jcraft%7Cjsch%7C0.1.50%7Cjar)

Comment: Thanks Ian, I've added my dependencies to the question for reference—I have been requiring jsch on runtime.

Comment: Does the stack trace of the original exception `e` give you any clues?

Comment: Wow, can't believe I forgot to check that! Looks like it can't find the jars.

Comment: Am I doing something wrong with the dependencies? Shouldn't they be pulled in at runtime?

Comment: I would have thought so, but maybe they're ending up on different classloaders or something (ant.jar on the bootstrap loader and ant-jsch on a child classloader)?  I don't know enough about the Grails 2.3 forked mode to be able to answer that question.